# Why was my HEIF tag deleted?

Tags: discussion, tags

I asked a question specific to the HEIF format, and created the HEIF tag accordingly.

However, my tag was deleted within a minute of the creation, not letting me enough time to add any information on it.

I feel that tag is really appropriate, after all, we do have a JPEG tag.

The question: 
[Can I use a HEIF decoder for commercial purpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44793422/can-i-use-a-heif-decoder-for-commercial-purpose)

Comment: Pretty sure licensing isn't on topic here.... (Not the main question here, but still important to point out imho)

Comment: I'm not sure about it neither to be honest, but I feel that this question might be quite useful for developers in the future; as the format becomes more prevalent.

Comment: IMO this question needs to asked to the company/person providing the decoder rather than in SO... It would be offtopic

Comment: Tag is now here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/heif/info Feel free to add information to it as you had planned to.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

So... This looks a bit unusual...

There's a daily script that does a bunch of stuff related to tags: updates the stored count of questions using that tag, removes bogus mappings, grants badges, etc. Oh, and it also destroys tags that aren't used on any questions...

...This task started running a couple minutes before you posted your question, and took a few minutes to run. So from the look of things, when it figured up the new counts for tags your question didn't exist yet... But when it got to the bit where it looked for tags that didn't have any counts, your tag (and question) had *juuust* been created.

So it saw a tag that (according to the list it'd just spent a couple minutes building) didn't have any questions associated with it... And promptly destroyed the tag.

I'd put this down as a "freak occurrence" - we only see a few tags created each day, the script only runs *once* a day, and so the chances of someone creating a new tag *while it runs* has to be pretty slim; you just got lucky.

So forget about HEIF for a bit and go buy some lottery tickets.

Comment: So wait... The script doesn't get the count at the same time it gets the list of tags?

Comment: For some reason, it appears to get the list of tags *twice* - once to count questions, once to delete unused. I might be reading that wrong, since it does sound wasteful - but it would explain what we saw here.

Comment: The SRE in me is now wondering what happens if the script, through some error, accidentally gets an empty response from the server for the "count questions" request.  Does it just blow away the entire tag list?

Comment: That should throw an exception and abort the entire process. The issue here is that nothing failed - the logic simply didn't think it worthwhile to worry about concurrency. Which is probably fair, given how few tags are created (and how quickly it runs on sites where many tags *are* created): a quick check suggests it has happened no more than 21 times in the entire history of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I should request a specific badge for this :D

Comment: if database stores age of the tag I would consider decreasing chance of data races like that by ignoring tags that are less than, say, one hour old

Comment: I once got six yahtzees in one game on a road trip once.  Stopped and bought a crapton of scratch off tickets.  They don't call them idiot tax for nothing :/

Comment: @Antzi you got one, but it was deleted right after.

Comment: @cat aww.... it isn't a thing...

Comment: This bug is so awesome that I wonder why does SO still have [transaction] tag.

Comment: @Braiam http://shouldiblameraceconditions.cf/

Comment: @cat you can also delete your previous invalid link